# How to calculate sum of multi column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle SQL to calculate value some column in my database
this is my LOG0104M table with values:

```
PRODUCT_CODE   PRODUCT_NAME   PACKING_STYLE   TOTAL_QUANTITY   QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN   SPAREBOX
  3300099        AP-1516D       30                  50                1                  NULL
  3330000        NEOSENSE       60                  20                1                  NULL
```

condition:

```
1. Fullbox =  (total_quantity / packing style)
2. SpareBox: (Base on value of Spare_Quantity)
 Spare_quantity = total_quantity - fullBox * packing_style.
    If spare qty = 0 => spare box = 0
    If spare qty > 0 => spare box = 1.
```

this is my query:

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (SELECT ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX FROM LOG0104M)
SELECT
  L55.PRODUCT_CODE 
  , L55.PRODUCT_NAME 
  , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
  , L55.PACKING_STYLE
  , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
  , L55.SPAREBOX
  , BC.FULLBOX

  ,CASE 
      WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) = 0  THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 0
      WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) != 0 THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 1
   END AS SPARE_QUANTITY

 FROM LOG0104M L55, BOXCOUNT BC
 GROUP BY 
    L55.PRODUCT_CODE
    , L55.PRODUCT_NAME
    , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
    , L55.PACKING_STYLE
    , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
    , BC.FULLBOX
    , L55.SPAREBOX
```

**(UPDATED)**

in condition CASE WHEN, sum of SPARE_QUANTITY:

```
if sum of SPARE_QUANTITY = 0 => SpareBox column will be 0, 
     and sum of SPARE_QUANTITY != 0 => SpareBox column will be 1
```

when run query, it happen an error following as:

```
SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

it seem happen an error at 12, 13, 14 row, how to fix the problem, many thank

Comment: I think you want to use `MOD()`...  `MOD(50, 30) = 20 => has space in box` which leads to `CASE WHEN MOD(quantity, style) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   AS spare_box`?

Comment: Hi @MatBailie: you're right, could you modify or detail query for me?

Comment: No, because I'm not clear on what you want.  Please could you edit your question and add some sample input data *(examples of what would be in LOG0104M)* and the final output you want for that example data?  This has a lot of handy tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes maybe i should edit my question to clear more

Comment: hi @MatBailie, I have updated my question, could you check it out ?

Comment: You're still not showing the example inputs and the desired outputs.  To be clear, I'm not asking for more SQL, I'm asking for data.  Enough data so that I can create a script to create an example table, populate it with your example data, write my own query to fulfil your requirements and then check my results against your desired results (Using such sites as http://dbfiddle.uk to demonstrate that they match).  All as per the link I gave you.

Comment: Also, maybe this will help you understand what I'm asking from you?  [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: hi @MatBailie: i have created new question with my explain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472007/how-to-calculate-sum-of-multi-column-with-case-when-condition-in-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `THEN` clauses in the `CASE` expression is incorrect:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) = 0  
     THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 0
----------^
     WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) != 0 
     THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 1
END AS SPARE_QUANTITY
```

Oracle doesn't have a Boolean data type in `SELECT` queries.

I am guessing that you simply want:

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) = 0  
      THEN 0
      WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) <> 0 
      THEN 1
 END) AS SPARE_QUANTITY
```

Or, if you want to eliminate the `CASE`:

```
ABS(SIGN(SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE))) AS SPARE_QUANTITY
```

Comment: hi @Gordon Linoff: yes i see, I only want to check condition of 'SPARE_QUANTITY'. If sum of SPARE_QUANTITY = 0 => SPAREBOX column is 0, and if sum of 'SPARE_QUANTITY' > 0 => SPAREBOX column is 1

Comment: I hope you can understand my meaning ^^

Comment: @luongkhanh . . . No, I do not.  Your question here is about a syntax error, which this answers.  If you have a different question about the right way to implement particular logic, I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: thank for your suggestion, I have created new question :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67472007/how-to-calculate-sum-of-multi-column-with-case-when-condition-in-oracle