# How to calculate sum of multi column with Case when condition in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using oracle SQL to calculate sum of value some columns in my database with case when in my condition

this is my LOG0104M table with values:

```
PRODUCT_CODE   PRODUCT_NAME   PACKING_STYLE   TOTAL_QUANTITY   QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN   SPAREBOX
 3300099        AP-1516D       30                  50                1                  NULL
 3330000        NEOSENSE       60                  20                1                  NULL
```

with value of columns above, i want to calculate output value of 'SPAREBOX' is 0 OR 1. To output value of 'SPAREBOX' is 0 OR 1, it will base on result of Spare_quantity with this recipe:

```
1. FullBox =  (Total_Quantity / Packing_Style)
2. Spare_quantity = Total_Quantity - FullBox * Packing_Style.
    If Spare_quantity  = 0 => SpareBox column = 0
    If Spare_quantity  > 0 => SpareBox column  = 1.
```

example:

```
1.  50 / 30 = FullBox (1,7)
2.   50 - 1.7 * 30 = Spare_quantity( 1,5)
     => Spare_quantity  > 0 and then SpareBox column = 1
```

expected result:

```
PRODUCT_CODE   PRODUCT_NAME   PACKING_STYLE   TOTAL_QUANTITY   QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN   SPAREBOX
 3300099        AP-1516D       30                  50                   1                1
```

this is my query:

```
WITH BOXCOUNT AS (                                                         
SELECT ROUND(SUM(TOTAL_QUANTITY/PACKING_STYLE)) AS FULLBOX FROM LOG0104M)
SELECT
   L55.PRODUCT_CODE 
   , L55.PRODUCT_NAME 
   , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
   , L55.PACKING_STYLE
   , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
   , L55.SPAREBOX
   , BC.FULLBOX

   ,CASE 
      WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) = 0  THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 0
      WHEN SUM(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY - BC.FULLBOX * L55.PACKING_STYLE) != 0 THEN L55.SPAREBOX = 1
   END AS SPARE_QUANTITY

  FROM LOG0104M L55, BOXCOUNT BC
  GROUP BY 
    L55.PRODUCT_CODE
    , L55.PRODUCT_NAME
    , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
    , L55.PACKING_STYLE
    , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
    , BC.FULLBOX
    , L55.SPAREBOX
```

it seem run with wrong result and not as expected result.

How to fix the problem ? many thank

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked 3 hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67469061/how-to-calculate-sum-of-multi-column-in-oracle

Comment: Yes it same with last question, but i have explained clear more

Comment: You should explain "clear more" in your original question, not open a new one. Closing this as a duplicate.

Comment: Note also that your explanation (especially the numerical example) makes no sense. Shouldn't "full boxes" be an integer, not a fractional number? If you allow it to be fractional, as in your example, the "spare boxes" will always be exactly 0, by trivial algebra. It's not 0 in your computation, only because you rounded 50/30 to 1.7; it is not clear why you did that. Rather, it seems that you want "full boxes" to be an integer, and if there are still items to pack, that don't require a **full** box, you need the "spare box" flag set to 1; but that is not how you explained it.

Comment: And if in fact that is your problem, you don't need to divide, then multiply, subtract, etc. You just need to use the `mod()` function.

Comment: Some times I despair.  @GordonLinoff asks the OP to open a new question, as addressing logic and syntax are materially different, then the community shoots the OP down for doing so.  People are too eager to close questions lately.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't provided much is the way of example.  If you want a rigorous answer you need to include enough example data to include all the behaviour you desire.

For example, why does your example input have two rows, but your desired results have one row?

Desperately trying to read between the lines I ***think*** that all you want is an extra column on each row, saying if that row has perfectly filled its boxes or not?

That would simply be a `CASE` expression using `MOD()`...

```
SELECT
     L55.PRODUCT_CODE 
   , L55.PRODUCT_NAME 
   , L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY
   , L55.PACKING_STYLE
   , L55.QUANTITY_IN_FULL_CTN
   , L55.SPAREBOX
   , CASE WHEN MOD(L55.TOTAL_QUANTITY, L55.PACKING_STYLE) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END   AS SPARE_QUANTITY
FROM
  LOG0104M L55
```

If that's not what you want, please add a ***full*** set of input data and a ***full*** set of results that correspond to that input, demonstrating ***exactly*** what you need.

If you're uncertain about what I mean, please refer to the links I gave you  previously.

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
- [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)